# How to get request country using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to retrieve requesting country using JavaScript or a free 3rd party service.

Anyways, do you know how I can simply get information like country, city, etc. from latitude and longitude values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this web service that can return JSON (along with using fetch API to make things simpler)

```js
let apiKey = '1be9a6884abd4c3ea143b59ca317c6b2';
fetch('https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=' + apiKey)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  });
```

Comment: No need to use jQuery, the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is fairly straight-forward to use